# I want the user to pick an image from the device then deal with that as a Bitmap myself, how do I achieve this with the help of content providers?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-bitmap, android-contentresolver, android-cursorloader

I have found several methods to achieve this but none of those seem straight forward and I don't understand the code in many of them. I read a little about content resolver, content provider and cursor recently and it seems that is the best practice to get a file from the user that's stored on the device.
Right now I am using this but it seems weird:

```
            val selectedImageUri: Uri = data.data!!
            val inputStream = contentResolver.query(selectedImageUri, Android.provider)
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
```

It uses a contnt resovler but with an input stream? I think that's a Java thing and not the best practice to achieve this on android. There is also this function

```
    fun getBitmapFromURI(uri: Uri): Bitmap? {
         val filePathColumn = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
         val cursor: Cursor? =
             this.contentResolver.query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null)
         if (cursor != null) {
             cursor.moveToFirst()
             val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0])
             val fImage = File(cursor.getString(columnIndex))
             cursor.close()
             val o2 = BitmapFactory.Options()

             return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fImage.absolutePath, o2)
         }
         return null
     }
```

I copied this from another thread on SO but again it feels so weird because i don't understand why we're asking the cursor to go to the first whatever why the rest of the parameters are passedi in null. Can someoen provide me with the best code that follows all the best practices and does things in a very efficient way?

Comment: "Right now I am using this but it seems weird" -- that should not compile, unless you defined your own `query()` extension function. Use `openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` for content identified by a `Uri`. "I think that's a Java thing and not the best practice to achieve this on android" -- um, well, all of that is using Android-specific functions that you will not find in the JDK. So, it's not really "a Java thing". "There is also this function" -- burn that with fire.

Comment: "Can someoen provide me with the best code that follows all the best practices and does things in a very efficient way?" -- the common recommendation is to use an image-loading library, such as Glide, Picasso, or [coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/). These know how to handle `Uri` values, how to do the work on background threads, how to cache the results, etc. Something like [coil's request syntax](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/#requests) is fairly easy to use, either in your own coroutine (`execute()`) or asynchronously managed by coil (`enqueue()`).

Comment: wait why burn that in fire? isnt the recommended approach to access files from a content provider to use a cursor loader and content resolver? does this not apply to images or am I missing something? I thought the way to access a file was to get a content provider that contains images and then do something with the cursor on a background thread? Also thanks I will try Glide or Picasso.

Comment: "isnt the recommended approach to access files from a content provider to use a cursor loader and content resolver?" -- no. You do now show how you are getting the `Uri`. The best-case scenario is you are using `ACTION_PICK` pointing to a `MediaStore` collection. That pretty much guarantees that you will get a filesystem path... and on Android 10+ you may not be able to read it anyway. And if you are doing anything else to get the `Uri` (e.g., `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`), there is no requirement for your `query()` to return a useful `Cursor`.